# tiered contextual filter?

Tags: views

I'm not sure if that is really the proper way of wording what i'm looking to do, but perhaps it will at least peak some curiosity.   I"m a bit uncertain how to explain it, so I'll do my best.  Just when I think i'm getting a handle of contextual filters a new challenge comes along, this one has me a bit stumped, I'll try to explain....

I have two content types.   **A**   **B**

**A** can reference **B**  as many values as it wants.  so I get a result like this:

A-
 -

- B1
- B2
- B3

I have a view which lists all of the **A** nodes...

- A1
- A2
- A3

What I'm attempting to do is this.  When looking at the page that shows the list of A's.
www.example.Alist.  I'm wanting to show in a block on the left, a cumulative list of all the
**B** nodes that **A** referenced. (without duplicates of course)  hope that makes sense to someone.  Having difficulty wrapping my head around how to go about it.  Thanks much for any guidance.

Comment: the list of "B" is indeed displayed as a block. the problem was getting them filtered based upon what list of A's I was looking at.   I failed to add to my explanation that A was being further filtered by their taxonomy term, so I would end up with multiple lists such as A-term1, A-term2....etc   When I was looking at the list of A-term1 nodes...I wanted to see all the "B"s that were referenced by nodes in that list.  The solution was to create a view that listed all the "B"s and set up a relationship to "A" and use a contextual filter that got it's filter value from the Term in the URL.

Comment: my head is still spinning from this one.